# Encode list and rotate it， decode with original list

Tags: python, list

This is the problem I had with functional programming.

Suppose I have a list `[2, 1, 3]`.
I can rotate it to get `[1, 3, 2]`.
Rotate again to get `[3, 2, 1]`.

I now have the encode function to get the encoded list.
Suppose it is called `Encoded [2, 1, 3]`.
After rotation, get `Encoded [1, 3, 2]`.

I now have the decode function.
When it receives `Encoded[2, 1, 3]`.
It can return `[2, 1, 3]`.

When it receives `Encoded [1, 3, 2]`.
It can still return  `[2, 1, 3]`.

in simple terms:

```
`decoded(encoded list) = list`

`decoded(rotate(encoded list)) = list`
```

There is also a condition that the range of the array of this list is 0..255 ,Other than that, no values are accepted.

My idea is that when I generate the Encoded list, I should do some work to make the decode function return the original list no matter what happens to the list

Any help is very important to me ,Thank you very much.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please remove  `java` and `haskell` tags, they are not relevant

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you still need the `original` list after you have `encoded` it. If you do this:

```
def rotate(lst: list):
    rotated = lst.copy()
    rotated.append(rotated[0])
    rotated.pop(0)
    return rotated

original = [2, 1, 3]
encoded = rotate(original)

print(original) # [2, 1, 3]
print(encoded) # [1, 3, 2]
```

you have both the lists so you can do whatever you have to do to `encoded` but you still the the `original`, no need to go back using a function.